# Use \foreach loop to execute macro with parameters of macro provided in a list

Tags: macros, expansion, foreach, comma-separated-list

I have to execute a macro a number of times, and would like to provide a list of the parameters to be executed.  So, instead of

```
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks[]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
```

I would prefer to simply set a list:

```
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    []{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com},
}
```

and then execute the `\FormatLinks` macro `\foreach` each element of this list.  I think this is probably some expansion related issue, but I was not able to get it to work. Currently, the output is:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \IfStrEq{#2}{}{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3}%
    }{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3~(#2)}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks[]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}

% Would prefer to define a list, and later execute the list:
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    []{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com},
}

\bigskip% 
Following should produce same results as above:\medskip\par
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \FormatLinks{\x}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Followup Questions: [Escaping special characters for use as a URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/escaping-special-characters-for-use-as-a-url) and [Passing escaped special characters for use as a URL through macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239880/passing-escaped-special-characters-for-use-as-a-url-through-macros).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are wrong here:

1. Expansion of `\x` should be done and not passed as a single argument to `\FormatLinks`.

   So, instead of

   ```
   \FormatLinks{\x}
   ```

   use

   ```
   \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
   ```

   since this will leave an expanded `\x` in the input stream for `\FormatLinks` to gobble up.
2. You have an empty item in the list (the last item);

   The empty list item implies that when you're passing `\x` to `\FormatLinks` it is expecting *at least* two arguments yet it receives none. So it gobbles whatever comes along and obviously does the wrong thing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \IfStrEq{#2}{}{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3}%
    }{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3~(#2)}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks[]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}

% Would prefer to define a list, and later execute the list:
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    []{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\bigskip% 
Following should produce same results as above:\medskip\par
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `\expandafter\FormatLinks{\x}`, but did _not_ try `\expandafter\FormatLinks\x`.

Answer (score 4):

Why the mysterious `\IfStr{#2}{}` when `xparse` already provides the infrastructure?

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    o%   #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
  \par
  \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~#2}}%
}
```

The problem is that you *don't* want to do `\FormatLinks{\x}` but want to expand `\x` before `\FormatLinks` sees it; however the braces should not be there. So `\expandafter\FormatLinks\x` would do.

Better, use a clist and a mapping function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    o%   #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
  \par
  \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~#2}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinksList}{}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_grill_linkparameters_clist { \FormatLinks ##1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_grill_linkparameters_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks[]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}

% Would prefer to define a list, and later execute the list:
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    []{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com},
}

\bigskip

Following should produce same results as above:\medskip\par

\FormatLinksList

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that `\IfValueT` would properly handle the case where the user specified `[]`.  That is really helpful to know.

Comment: @PeterGrill It returns true *only if* the user specifies `[...]`. There are also `\IfValueF` and `\IfValueTF`; `\IfValueT` is equivalent to `\IfNoValueF`, but in this case it's semantically preferable the “positive” one.