# Escaping special characters for use as a URL

Tags: macros, urls, foreach, comma-separated-list

If a url contain special characters (`~` and `#`) using it as

```
\href{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastmmg/ssguide/set_work.html#4_32}{people.brunel.ac.uk}
```

works just fine. But, I would like to have macro list which contains these URLs and process them at a later time as I did in [Use \foreach loop to execute macro with parameters of macro provided in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/use-foreach-loop-to-execute-macro-with-parameters-of-macro-provided-in-a-list). So, I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    [people.brunel.ac.uk]{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastmmg/ssguide/set_work.html#4_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}
```

With the offending line commented I get:

[image]

This works fine for the 1st and 3rd case, but not the one with the special TeX characters. I tried escaping them but that doesn't quite work as the links are not click able.

So, what escapes me is how to escape the special characters in such a list?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~#2}}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\par\hspace*{1.0cm}\href{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastmmg/ssguide/set_work.html#4_32}{people.brunel.ac.uk}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}

% Prefer to define a list, and later execute the list:
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    %% What changes do I need to make to the following URL to get it pass through the macros.
    % [people.brunel.ac.uk]{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastmmg/ssguide/set_work.html#4_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\bigskip% 
Following should produce same results as above:\medskip\par
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Questions: [Use \foreach loop to execute macro with parameters of macro provided in a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/use-foreach-loop-to-execute-macro-with-parameters-of-macro-provided-in-a-list) and [Passing escaped special characters for use as a URL through macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239880/passing-escaped-special-characters-for-use-as-a-url-through-macros).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~#2}}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatLinks*[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com}
\par\hspace*{1.0cm}\href{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastmmg/ssguide/set_work.html#4_32}{people.brunel.ac.uk}
\FormatLinks{Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}

% Prefer to define a list, and later execute the list:
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    %% What changes do I need to make to the following URL to get it pass through the macros.
    {people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\bigskip% 
Following should produce same results as above:\medskip\par
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So I can't have an optional parameter preceding the url?

Comment: @PeterGrill yes see the google one, but the brunel one didnt hav ethe mandatory link text (the syntax you defined is optional * optional arg, mandatory link text, mandatory link, (or so it seemed)

Comment: Opppss.. Sorry, I really should be able to read my own code... I'd be nice if I had some wine as an excuse but all I have had is coffee. So, the only thing I can think of is _old age_ :-).. Thanks. Again!