# Passing escaped special characters for use as a URL through macros

Tags: macros, urls, xstring, comma-separated-list

From an earlier question on [Escaping special characters for use as a URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/escaping-special-characters-for-use-as-a-url), using `\string` to escape the special URL characters in the second example works great:

```
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}
```

`\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters` defines a list of parameters in`\MyFormatLinkParameters`:

```
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%
```

However, if I instead use

```
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew}[2][TypeB]{%
    %\edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#2}% Don't assign it here directly, 
                                        % but pass it along 
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {TypeA}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA{#2}}%
        {TypeB}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB{#2}}%
    }[\typeout{*** ERROR: Unknown link type: #1}]%
}%
```

which passes the list of parameters to another macro, `\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA` or `\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB`, there is a problem in processing the special characters.  Things works fine for cases which do not use special TeX characters as per the MWE below:

[image]

### Notes

- In the MWE, the problem case is commented out in the call to `\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew`.  Uncomment the `people.brunel.ac.uk` line to reproduce the problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~(#2)}}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%


%% \DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew (compared to \DefineMyFormatLinkParameters) has 
%% one extra level of macro processing based on the optional #1 parameter
\newcommand*{\Title}{}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#1}%
    \def\Title{Type A Links}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#1}%
    \def\Title{Type B Links}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew}[2][TypeB]{%
    %\edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#2}% Don't assign it here directly, 
                                        % but pass it along 
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {TypeA}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA{#2}}%
        {TypeB}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB{#2}}%
    }[\typeout{*** ERROR: Unknown link type: #1}]%
}%


\begin{document}
% ------------------------------- First version: works fine.
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}%


%------------------------------- Second version: Not working if uncomment 
%                                people.burnel.ac.uk.  Only difference
%                                is that it has one extra level of macro
%                                processing which causes some problem!
\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew[TypeB]{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    %{people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\bigskip\Title:% 
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParametersNew {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a followup to: [Escaping special characters for use as a URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239862/escaping-special-characters-for-use-as-a-url) and [Use \foreach loop to execute macro with parameters of macro provided in a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/use-foreach-loop-to-execute-macro-with-parameters-of-macro-provided-in-a-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I'd use xstring if you already have l3 and pgf loaded but anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatLinks}{%
    s%   #1 =* not used yet
    O{}% #2 = optional title
    m%   #3 = Mandatory title
    m%   #4 = URL Link
}{%
    \par
    \hspace*{1.0cm}\href{#4}{#3\IfValueT{#2}{~(#2)}}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFormatLinkParameters}{}% Initialize
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParameters{#1}%
}%


%% \DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew (compared to \DefineMyFormatLinkParameters) has 
%% one extra level of macro processing based on the optional #1 parameter
\newcommand*{\Title}{}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#1}%
    \def\Title{Type A Links}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB}[1]{%
    \edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#1}%
    \def\Title{Type B Links}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew}[2][TypeB]{%
    %\edef\MyFormatLinkParametersNew{#2}% Don't assign it here directly, 
                                        % but pass it along 
\edef\tempz{\unexpanded{#2}}%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {TypeA}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeA{\tempz}}%
        {TypeB}{\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersTypeB{\tempz}}%
    }[\typeout{*** ERROR: Unknown link type: #1}]%
}%


\begin{document}
% ------------------------------- First version: works fine.
\DefineMyFormatLinkParameters{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParameters {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}%


%------------------------------- Second version: Not working if uncomment 
%                                people.burnel.ac.uk.  Only difference
%                                is that it has one extra level of macro
%                                processing which causes some problem!
\DefineMyFormatLinkParametersNew[TypeB]{%
    *[Main Search Site]{Google}{http://www.google.com},
    {people.brunel.ac.uk}{http://people.brunel.ac.uk/\string~mastmmg/ssguide/set\string_work.html\string#4\string_32},
    {Yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
}

\bigskip\Title:% 
\foreach \x in \MyFormatLinkParametersNew {%
    \typeout{DEBUG: "\x"}
    \expandafter\FormatLinks\x
}

\end{document}
```